# which opengl version is suitable for android?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I'm looking for good OpenGL ES tutorial for android from basics. i got confused about the versions of OpenGL ES. Which version of OpenGL ES is suitable and easy to develop the 3D objects to map AR for android.

Thank You....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGLES 2.0 is supported from Android 2.2 and up.

[The official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html) has a rather good guide to get started from scratch.

To get going with augmented reality you might be interested in using a library, such as [AndAR](https://code.google.com/p/andar/).